# Android : after changing value of Shared Preference key in service class, it displays default value

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, static-variables

After changing value of session key in service class, it displays default value, while calling activity using pendingIntent

0) here is my SharedPreference file

```
public class SessionCounter {
 SharedPreferences pref;
    Editor editor;       
    Context _context;
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;        
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "AndroidCounterPref";   
    private static final String sessionCounter = "session_Counter";

    public SessionCounter(Context context){
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    public void createCounterSession(Integer name){        
        editor.putInt(sessionCounter, name);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public int getCounterSession(){         
        int val=pref.getInt(sessionCounter, 0);
        return val; 
    }
```

}

1) here is my service class `CaptureImagesService` class

```
    public static int COUNTER=-1;  

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){                   
    context=this;
    this.startId=startId;       
    randomTime=getRandom(time_interval) * 30 * 1000 ;       
    timer1=new Timer();
    timer1.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            sessionCounter.createCounterSession(1);
            startAlarm();               
        }
    }, randomTime);     
    return START_STICKY;
}

 public void startAlarm()
 {  
      sessionCounter.createCounterSession(1);
         manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);         

            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(CaptureImagesService.this, HomeActivity.class);
            alarmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 1001, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            Log.d("CaptureImagesService", "after pendingIntent");    

            long whenToTrigger=Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();               
            manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, whenToTrigger, pendingIntent);
 }
```

2) Here is my MainActivity `onResume` method where i want to use this value and if value of `COUNTER` is 1 then perform action

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();       
    if(sessionCounter.getCounterSession()==1)
          WakeUpDevice();
          askForPicture();  
          //etc
    }
}

public void addCall(View v) {       

    if (sfStore.getString(KEY_CURRENT_CALL_ID, "-1").equalsIgnoreCase("-1")) {
          startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), CaptureImagesService.class));
    }
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Is `CaptureImagesService.onStartCommand()` ever called?

Comment: where are you starting the service? please post those codes..

Comment: on addCall button click service is started

Comment: Add a log in Service onStartCommand to actually verify if the service is actually started

Comment: yes, i debug the code and put logs to show changes , service onStartCommand and startAlarm method is called with COUNTER=1, and when MainActivity onResume is called, if condition is getting false because of COUNTER=-1

Comment: It seems quite **obvious**. When the MainActivity **resumes**, the app has been **restarted**. Therefore, since **you don't save and reload** the changed value, the Class gets its default value. Until you click on the Button. Only **then** the value changes.

Comment: thanx @Der Golem it works ,i set counter =1 in onRestart method but it called every time i resumes activity, i only want counter =1 if it comes from service startAlarm method

Comment: So, when you change the value, **save** it in your Shared Preferences. Then, in `onResume()`, **load** it. And change it again (not saving it) when the Alarm fires.

Comment: I have also tried shared preferences , but no difference.

Comment: plesae post your manifest

Comment: thank you, but i already changed the code and used broadcast receiver

Comment: Please create an answer to your question and accept that. It will help others who have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used getBroadcast instead of getActivity

```
public class CaptureBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver{

public static boolean counterNew;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    counterNew=true;        //and check if counter is true then
                            // do some code in onResume method of HomeActivity
    contextStart=context;

    Intent intentHome=new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
    intentHome.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intentHome);
}
}
```

In HomeActivity onResume

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();   

    if(CaptureBroadcast.counterNew==true){
                 // some code
     }
}
```